# DataFrame Pandas repeated dates questions

Tags: python, pandas

my very first time here. This is my pandas' dataframe with repeated datetimes:

```
            ticker  close
datetime        
1994-07-04  WEG     48.00
1994-07-04  ITSA    51.00
1994-07-04  ALPA    131.00
1994-07-05  WEG     49.03
1994-07-05  ITSA    52.60
1994-07-05  ALPA    132.30
... ... ...
```

and i want it to be like these:

```
                WEG     ITSA    ALPA    ....
    datetime                                
    1994-07-04  48.00   51.00   131.00      
    1994-07-05  49.03   52.60   132.30  
    1994-07-06  48.40   55.00   133.00  
    1994-07-07  49.00   56.98   134.00  
    1994-07-08  51.00   59.50   136.00
    ... ... ...
```

How can i do it?
Thanks

Comment: try ``df.pivot(index=None, columns='ticker', values = 'close')``